# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: dbContextTransaction - IntegrationEvent c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, microservices, event-bus

I am using EventBus to notify the other microservices. When a Customer is Saved. Event integration has to keep the other microservices in sync
I'm doing an event integration. I got an example from Microsoft about the Event Bus.

When application arrives in this method

```
public async Task AddAndSaveEventAsync(IntegrationEvent evt)
{
     await _eventLogService.SaveEventAsync(evt, _osDataContext.GetCurrentTransaction.GetDbTransaction());
}
```

Soon after entering through this method, it goes through another method where the error occurs

```
namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage
{
    public static class DbContextTransactionExtensions
    {
        public static DbTransaction GetDbTransaction([NotNullAttribute] this IDbContextTransaction dbContextTransaction);
    }
}
```

It returns me an error: `Value can not be null. Parameter name: dbContextTransaction`

I have my database context class

```
public partial class ApplicationDataContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDataContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    private IDbContextTransaction _currentTransaction;
    public IDbContextTransaction GetCurrentTransaction => _currentTransaction;

    public async Task BeginTransactionAsync()
    {
        _currentTransaction = _currentTransaction ?? await Database.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    }

    public async Task CommitTransactionAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await SaveChangesAsync();
            _currentTransaction?.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            RollbackTransaction();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (_currentTransaction != null)
            {
                _currentTransaction.Dispose();
                _currentTransaction = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
        try
        {
            _currentTransaction?.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (_currentTransaction != null)
            {
                _currentTransaction.Dispose();
                _currentTransaction = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public const string DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "serviceorder";

    public DbSet<model.ServiceOrder> ServiceOrder { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ServiceOrderType> ServiceOrderType { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContactRole> ContactRole { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DocumentType> DocumentType { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Document> Document { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ServiceOrderTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ServiceOrderConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CustomerConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new DocumentConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new DocumentTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContactConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContactRoleConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Comment: `_osDataContext.GetCurrentTransaction` is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

This error was basically. For not opening connection, that is. I was making the call and was not opening a connection.

```js
    public async Task AddAndSaveEventAsync(IntegrationEvent evt)
        {
            await ResilientTransaction.New(_osDataContext).ExecuteAsync(async () =>
               {
                   await _osDataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                   await _eventLogService.SaveEventAsync(evt, _osDataContext.Database.CurrentTransaction.GetDbTransaction());
               });
        }
```